# How to set a state hook and change css class when clicking a button

Tags: css, reactjs

I have 3 buttons. When you click them, they set the lineType state of the penOptions Hook. However, I also want the button to change css class when clicked too, so that the background color of the button changes.

I have tried calling two different functions in the onClick, but it doesn't seem to actually fire both functions.

Here is what I have for one button currently:

```js
<input
    className="pen-buttons"
    type="button"
    value="Solid"
    onClick={e => {setPenOptions({...penOptions, lineType: "solid"})}}
/>
```

I expect the lineType to change depending on which button is clicked and I would like the last button clicked to have a blue background color.

I attempted to change the css like this:

```js
className={penOptions.changeClassSolid}
onClick={e => {setPenOptions({...penOptions, lineType: "dot"}); handleClick();}}
```

and then calling this on the onClick as well:

```js
    function handleClick() {
        console.log("clicked");
        if (penOptions.lineType === "solid") {
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassSolid: "pen-buttons--active"});
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassDash: "pen-buttons"});
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassDot: "pen-buttons"});
        } else if (penOptions.lineType === "dash") {
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassSolid: "pen-buttons"});
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassDash: "pen-buttons--active"});
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassDot: "pen-buttons"});
        } else if (penOptions.lineType === "dot") {
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassSolid: "pen-buttons"});
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassDash: "pen-buttons"});
            setPenOptions({...penOptions, changeClassDot: "pen-buttons--active"});
        };
    };
```

But that didn't work.

Comment: I don't see any code making changes to css.

Comment: Edited it to show my attempt.

Comment: I don't see any issue from looking at your code, but i've come up with my version really quickly, please see here https://codesandbox.io/s/pqzek 

It works perfectly, my guess is that you change you set your state back-to-back in the same call which makes you lose an update. Which is what doing `setPenOptions` and then calling `handleClick` which also calls `setPenOptions`

Comment: Ya i think you're right about that. if i console.log the penOptions.lineType in handleClick() it's always one behind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to go this route, then this is probably what you're trying to achieve with your code.

```
function Pen() {
  const [penOptions, setPenOptions] = React.useState({
    lineType: '',
    changeClassSolid: 'pen-buttons',
    changeClassDash: 'pen-buttons',
    changeClassDot: 'pen-buttons'
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const opts = {
      changeClassSolid: 'pen-buttons',
      changeClassDash: 'pen-buttons',
      changeClassDot: 'pen-buttons'
    };

    if (penOptions.lineType === 'solid') {
      setPenOptions({
        ...opts,
        lineType: penOptions.lineType,
        changeClassSolid: 'pen-buttons--active'
      });
    }
    if (penOptions.lineType === 'dash') {
      setPenOptions({
        ...opts,
        lineType: penOptions.lineType,
        changeClassDash: 'pen-buttons--active'
      });
    }
    if (penOptions.lineType === 'dot') {
      setPenOptions({
        ...opts,
        lineType: penOptions.lineType,
        changeClassDot: 'pen-buttons--active'
      });
    }
  }, [penOptions.lineType]);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{penOptions.lineType}</p>
      <button className={penOptions.changeClassSolid} onClick={() => setPenOptions({...penOptions, lineType: 'solid'})}>solid</button>
      <button className={penOptions.changeClassDash} onClick={() => setPenOptions({...penOptions, lineType: 'dash'})}>dash</button>
      <button className={penOptions.changeClassDot} onClick={() => setPenOptions({...penOptions, lineType: 'dot'})}>dot</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This made the penOptions.lineType stop changing.

Comment: You're probably doing something wrong. Here's a link to the same code but tweaked so you can see it working properly https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-rain-z8vbi